# How to solve the error of the "missing Location in call to Date" in golang

Tags: go

I have written a golang program to generate the start date and end date of the month for different locations

```
if month != "" && year != "" {
    var monthInt, _ = strconv.Atoi(month)
    var yearInt, _ = strconv.Atoi(year)
    timeZone, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Pheonix")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)// nil
    }
    // currentLocation := time.Now().Location(timeZone) // when I use this it will works 
    // both are of same type 
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(timeZone))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(time.UTC))
    firstOfMonth := time.Date(yearInt, time.Month(monthInt), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, timeZone)
    onlyStartDate := strings.Split(firstOfMonth.Format("2006-01-02 00:00:00 -0000"), " ")
    lastOfMonth := firstOfMonth.AddDate(0, 1, -1).Format("2006-01-02 00:00:00 -0000")
    onlyLastDate := strings.Split(lastOfMonth, " ")
    merchantDb.GetProvidersOfTheMonth(onlyStartDate[0], onlyLastDate[0])
}
```

But when I run this code it will give me the error of the:-

> time: missing Location in call to Date

Why this error is generating and how I will solve this error?

Please any suggestions!

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by `LoadLocation`.

Comment: @peter can you explain how i resolve it

Comment: @Doe, by inspecting the error. Ignoring errors is a waste of time. Don't do it.

Comment: @peter okay I will take care of this :)

Comment: Using this library https://godoc.org/4d63.com/tz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `America/Phoenix`, not `America/Pheonix`.

```
timeZone, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Phoenix")
```

For more information about list of available time zones string, please see: https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go

Comment: thanks for this it resolve my problem omg its mistake of timeZone string I'm giving Thankyou for your precious time